# GCP | Cloud Monitoring | How to group projects for display on Cloud Monitoring Dashboard?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I've been trying to group projects on our GCP environment for cloud monitoring. The purpose is to have a dashboard that displays CPU/memory utilization by groups, with each group consists of a few projects on GCP.

So far, I've tried the Groups function under Cloud Monitoring service, but that doesn't allow the grouping of projects.

Is there any way to group projects for monitoring purpose here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can set up monitoring for multiple GCP projects: using the gcloud CLI or in the GCP console. follow these [instructions](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/infrastructure-monitoring/cloud-platform-monitoring/google-cloud-platform-monitoring/monitor-multiple-projects).

You can also refer to this [lab](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/621?parent=catalog) and [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/settings)

Answer (score 0):

On the Settings page, you can create a Workspace, to combine projects. System will prompt you to create a new project which will include all monitored projects, OR existing project can be used to combine other projects.

On this, you can get what you need easily.